# jvm heap usage calculation

Tags: jvm, heap-memory

I need to capture jvm heap usage from gc.out logs. This is what I see in the logs:

```
178.658: [GC (Metadata GC Threshold)  127089K->17827K(502784K), 0.0398140 secs]
178.698: [Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold)  17827K->17031K(502784K), 0.0482840 secs]
180.498: [GC (Allocation Failure)  148615K->20762K(502784K), 0.0082820 secs]
```

Can someone please explain what are these fields mean?

Answer (score 0):

The field order is as below:

1. Time in secs when GC started relative to JVM start

   - Values from log are **178.658, 178.698** and **180.498**
2. GC type: It can be Minor/Major/Full

   - Values from log are **GC, Full GC** and  **GC**

     - From this, we can only say whether it was full GC or not. You need more detailed logging to see what part of memory exactly was cleared - young, tenured or metaspace (or some combination of these) which helps decide exact type of GC.
3. Reason For GC getting triggered

   - Values from log are **Metadata GC Threshold, Metadata GC Threshold** and  **Allocation Failure**

     - Metadata GC Threshold: Metaspace is the Java 8 replacement of Permgen. So this is triggered because you ran out of permgen space.
     - Allocation Failure: No space left to allocate new objects.
4. Used heap size before and after GC (in the format before->after)

   - Values from log are **127089K->17827K, 17827K->17031K** and **148615K->20762K**
5. Total heap size

   - Value from log is **502784K**
6. Duration of GC

   - Values from log are **0.0398140 secs, 0.0482840 secs** and **0.0082820 secs**